# RSpec Capybara have_selector Test Not Working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I have a very simple RSpec Capybara have_selector() that doesn't seem to be working and I can't figure out why... but probably something simple.

Here's the RSpec request test:

```
describe 'with valid information'
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  before do
    fill_in 'Email', with: user.email
    fill_in 'Password, with: user.password
    click_button 'Login'
  end
  it { should have_selector('p', text: user.first_name) }
  ...
end
```

In the `new.html.erb` for the session, I just have something like this:

```
<% if logged_in? %>
  <p><%= current_user.first_name %></p>
<% else %>
  <%= form_for(:session, url: sessions_path) do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

The login form `session#new` works perfectly in the browser. I can login just fine and am able to view the first name in a `p` tag. The problem seems to be the capybara part, because the other `it` test checking for the `h1` tag on the page (which is present regardless of being logged in) works fine.

Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Thanks in advance for any help!!

Comment: Have you checked the HTML that is being rendered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More than likely, your login is failing for one reason or another.

Change your test to look like this:

```
it "should show me my first name" do
  save_and_open_page
  should have_selector('p', text: user.first_name)
end
```

That will open your browser and show you the page as the test browser currently sees it. (You may need to add the `launchy` gem to your Gemfile.)

There are a few other diagnostics that would help, for instance, adding a test or a `puts` that checks what page you landed on, such as:

```
it "redirects to the home page after log in" do
  current_path.should == root_path
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I tried using the `save_and_open_page` and it shows the login page despite the `before` method logging the user in with Capybara. I don't think the login is working, but I'm not sure why, since it works in real life...

Comment: It turns out that I forgot to create a new user after adding in the `before_save` to create a token... But, I'm marking yours the answer because it's what led me to the solution!

Answer (score 0):

```
fill_in 'Password, with: user.password
```

not like that. You should use this line,

```
fill_in 'Password', with: user.password
```

Comment: Sorry, yes, this was a typo on my end, but not in the application.